# Out of Memory When Looping Through 22 Rows in a Single Column

Tags: excel, vba, memory

Excel is giving me a 007 Memory Error.

There are 160 sheets in this book. My aim is to go to each sheet, loop through Column B to find where Profit lives, and then go to the next column and pull the profit number out. Then consolidate that info on a single sheet at the end.

I will be looping through a larger range (say, A1:G20). I assumed this large range was the issue, but I still get a memory error with just 20 rows of column B.

```vb
Sub EstimGP()
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim EstimGP As Integer

rng = Range("B1:B22")
a = Application.Worksheets.Count

'Select Worksheet
For i = 1 To (a - 1)
    Worksheets(i).Activate

    'Loop cells
    For Each Cell In rng

        'THIS IS WHERE THE MEMORY ERROR OCCURS
        If Cells.Value = "Estimated GP%:" Or "Estimated GP%: " Then EstimGP = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Worksheets("SummaryData").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = EstimGP
    Next Cell
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: BTW this is not doing what you think it is.  `rng` is a specific range on a specific sheet, namely the sheet that is active at the time this is run.  Even though you are iterating the worksheets, `rng` will always refer to the range of cells on the first sheet, the one that was active when the code was run.  Also `If Cells.Value = "Estimated GP%:" Or "Estimated GP%: "` should be: `If Cells.Value = "Estimated GP%:" Or Cells.Value = "Estimated GP%: "`

Comment: Cells is not Cell. Use `Option Explicit` ! And rng does not change just because you activate another sheet !

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you. Had a feeling I was just using some function completely wrong.  A few more tutorial videos it is...

Comment: Side note, consider hitting TAB whenever you begin a new block (`If...Then`, `For...Next`, `Sub...End Sub`, etc.); proper indentation helps avoiding compile errors caused by mismatched/intertwined blocks, and generally helps with readability.

Comment: Your code is telling me that there is only one cell containing `Estimated GP%:` per worksheet (this will overwrite: `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = EstimGP`). So is the expected result 160 values in column `J` of `SummaryData`? Is the 'lookup' range always `"B1:B22"` or is it rather `"B1:B" & LastRow` (possibly `B2...` if headers)? Please do clarify. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68277708/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cells` is an [implicit ActiveSheet reference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) (Rubberduck can spot them all for you); without parameters it returns a `Range` object representing *all* cells of whatever the `ActiveSheet` is (that's over a million rows times over 16K columns!).

When it represents more than a single cell, `Range.Value` gives you the *values* of the cells in a 2D `Variant` array.

So `If Cells.Value = "some string literal"` would normally fail because you cannot use comparison operators between an array and a literal value: that's likely just a typo where you meant to write `If Cell.Value...` referring to the `Cell` loop variable; consider renaming it `CurrentCell`, and then the condition becomes `If CurrentCell.Value...`. Note that the loop changes which sheet is active, so any implicit `ActiveSheet` references in that loop are dangerous and will not produce the desired outcome.

The Boolean expression is also problematic: you have `If something = "abc" Or "xyz"`; comparison/logical operators have 2 operands, one on each side, and they're expected to be Boolean expressions, so you want to change that to `If something = "abc" Or something = "xyz"`.

Consider changing the outer loop to `For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, then you can work off `CurrentSheet` without needing to `Activate` them.